# Performance Testing ActiveMQ Artemis using AMQP protocol

Tags: jmeter, message-queue, amqp, loadrunner, activemq-artemis

I need to test ActiveMQ Artemis using AMQP protocol (not JMS or MQTT). I am completely new on testing message queues.

Thanks in advance.

Please assist on how to try this in Jmeter or LoadRunner tool.

Comment: It's worth noting that ActiveMQ Artemis actually ships with it own set of [performance tools](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tools.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JMeter there is [JMeter AMQP Plugin](https://github.com/aliesbelik/jmeter-amqp-plugin). If it's not sufficient for your needs, i.e. doesn't support SASL and you explicitly need this authentication - you will need to go for [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) or even to create your own [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) using client libraries of your AMPQ broker.

For loadrunner the approach should be [more or less the same](https://community.microfocus.com/adtd/loadrunner/f/sws-loadrunner_sf/520382/activemq-artemis-performance-testing-through-amqp-protocol)